# Convert UTC date received from server to local timzone date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, utc

Working with Javascript, I want to convert the UTC date received from the server to the local timezone date object in the client's browser.

Which function/code do I have to use in Javascript?
For example, converting this UTC date: '2021-01-20T17:40:35'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format '2021-01-20T17:40:35' is supported by ECMA-262, but without a timezone it's parsed as local. If you want it parsed as UTC just add "Z" to set the offset to 0, so:

```
new Date('2021-01-20T17:40:35' + 'Z')
```

parses the string as UTC. Then the local date and time is returned by the various [*get** methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or just [*toString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

However, if you want a truely robust function, parse it manually, e.g.

```
// Get the parts
let [Y, M, D, H, m, s] = '2021-01-20T17:40:35'.split(/\D/);
// Treat as UTC
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s));
```

There are many questions on formatting dates. Any *toString* method that doesn't include the characters "UTC" or "ISO" will return local values based on the host system's regional settings for timezone and DST.

E.g.

```js
let [Y, M, D, H, m, s] = '2021-01-20T17:40:35'.split(/\D/);
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s));

// Formatted as specified in ECMA-262
console.log(date.toString());
// So-called "locale aware" string, based on language
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
// In another timezone for Antarctica/McMurdo
console.log(date.toLocaleString('default', {timeZone: 'Antarctica/McMurdo', timeZoneName: 'short'}));
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems this is what I am looking for. However, after parsing, the month changed to Feb... my result is as below (My timezone is GMT+7).

Sun Feb 21 2021 00:40:35 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
2/21/2021, 12:40:35 AM
2/21/2021, 6:40:35 AM GMT+13

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot month - 1. Doh.